# Adding a row to my df with a resulting value

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a df of 5 rows and 430 columns . 
I would like to multiply each value in a column by `[5,4,3,2,1]`, divide by the `sum`of the values in each column  and the corresponding output  add it as a new row to each column.

where my df looks like this:

```
df1=
                          CO2           SO4           SE6           NH1
test1                     4.0           1.0           8.0           0.0 ..
test2                    10.0           1.0           3.0           4.0 ..
test3                    11.0           6.0           4.0           1.0 ..
test4                     0.0          11.0           0.0           1.0 ..
test5                     1.0           6.0           0.0           1.0 ..
```

I would like the following output:

```
                          CO2           SO4           SE6           NH1
test1                     4.0           1.0           8.0           0.0 ..
test2                    10.0           1.0           3.0           4.0 ..
test3                    11.0           6.0           4.0           1.0 ..
test4                     0.0          11.0           0.0           1.0 ..
test5                     1.0           6.0           0.0           1.0 ..
rank                      value         value         value         value
```

where value is the following math operation:

```
(test1*5 + test2*4 + test3*3 + test4*2 + test5*1)/(test1+test2+test3+test4+test5)
```

This is what I have tried:

```
for i in range(len(df1.columns)):
    rank= np.dot(df1.iloc[:,i],[5,4,3,2,1])/np.sum(df1.iloc[:,i])
    (df1.iloc[:,i]).loc['rank']=rank
print(df1)
```

However it outputs the initial input. 
How can I return the df with the last row `rank`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
a = [5,4,3,2,1]

df1.loc['rank'] = df1.T.dot(a).div(df1.sum())
print (df1)
             CO2   SO4       SE6       NH1
test1   4.000000   1.0  8.000000  0.000000
test2  10.000000   1.0  3.000000  4.000000
test3  11.000000   6.0  4.000000  1.000000
test4   0.000000  11.0  0.000000  1.000000
test5   1.000000   6.0  0.000000  1.000000
rank    3.615385   2.2  4.266667  3.142857
```

Verifying:

```
for i in range(len(df1.columns)):
    rank= np.dot(df1.iloc[:,i],[5,4,3,2,1])/np.sum(df1.iloc[:,i])
    print (rank)

3.61538461538
2.2
4.26666666667
3.14285714286
```